# How to send POST and refresh page with React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have written a simple form that sends a post request with data to the server. On click of the submit button, I want to clear the form, so I create a function that refreshes the page. The function works correctly, but now the data is not sent to the server.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class PostForm extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        surname: '',
        country: ''
    }
}

changeHandler = e => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
}

clearFunc = () => {
    window.location.reload(false);
}

submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/human/add/', this.state)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        });
}


render() {
    const {id, name, surname, country} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <form id="input-form" onSubmit={() => {
                this.submitHandler();
                this.clearFunc()
            }}>
                <div>
                    <input type="number" name="id" value={id} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="surname" value={surname} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="country" value={country} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default PostForm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move this line `this.clearFunc()` inside `submitHandler`, in that `then` block, like so:

```
submitHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.state);
  axios
    .post("http://localhost:8080/human/add/", this.state)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      this.clearFunc();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Also, if it's just to empty the form, there is no need to refresh the page, you could simply do so:

```
clearFunc = () => {
  this.setState({
    id: "",
    name: "",
    surname: "",
    country: "",
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you did it in the wrong flow. If you want to clear the form after submitting it, mostly in React App, you only need to set all states to empty string after the POST has succeeded (which means we will put it inside then()).

It would looks something like this:

```
clearForm = () => {
    // use this to reset the states
    this.setState({
        id: '',
        name: '',
        surname: '',
        country: ''
    })
}

submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/human/add/', this.state)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            clearForm() // <-- call the function here
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        });
}
```

Why you should not put the clearForm() inside form onSubmit? Because we never know the POST request will succeeds or not. It's a good idea to keep the values is POST request has error response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to refresh the page, as long as you are using the `e.preventDefault()` you are stopping the default behavior of refreshing the page by the form.

if all you want is to empty the form, then you can use the `document.form.reset()` where form is the name you have assigned to the form.